# unittest for both python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-3.2

I'm struggling to make a unittest work in both 2.7.3 and 3.2.3 (the versions that come with ubuntu 12.04)

Basically the problems are:

- I need to `assertEqual` strings that have unicode, so python2 uses u'asdf' and python 3.2 has no such thing (I believe they were reintroduced in 3.3). Is there a way I can represent a string parameter to `assertEqual` in a way it will compare equal to `u'asdf'` and compiles in python 3.2?
- I need to `assertRegex` a few outputs, but in python2.7 its called `assertRegexpMatched`. Should I create a custom method that uses the right one depending on the version running the code? how?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating this function to replace u"asdf":

```
def u(s):
    if sys.version_info[0]==3:
        return s
    else:
        return unicode(s.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\'), "unicode_escape")
```

And adding this method in my test class:

```
def assertRegexp(self, a, b):
    if sys.version_info >= (3,2):
        return self.assertRegex(a, b)
    else:
        return self.assertRegexpMatches(a, b)
```